# Нужен ли абзац для прямой речи, пишущейся в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, диалог, абзац

К примеру: схема, когда прямая речь предшествует словам автора.

"Я приду сегодня вечером", — сказал мальчик.

Нужен ли в этом случае абзац и может ли он быть в принципе, если прямая речь берется в кавычки?

Answer (score 2):

А зачем нам обязательно абзац?
Вот у Булгакова оформление в "Собачьем сердце".

Прямая речь в кавычках **внутри абзаца.**

> Зина внесла серебряное крытое блюдо, в котором что-то ворчало. Запах от блюда шел такой, что рот пса немедленно заполнился жидкой слюной. **«Сады Семирамиды!», – подумал он и застучал, как палкой, по паркету хвостом.**
>   .  .  .  .
>   Филипп Филиппович сжал губы и ничего не сказал. Опять как оглашенный загремел телефон. Филипп Филиппович, ничего не спрашивая, молча сбросил трубку с рогулек так, что она, покрутившись немного, повисла на голубом шнуре. Все вздрогнули. **«Изнервничался старик», – подумал Борменталь, а Швондер, сверкая глазами, поклонился и вышел.**

Прямая речь в кавычках **отдельным абзацем.**

> «Не нравится мне. Не нравится», – пес обиженно нахмурился и стал шляться по квартире, а вся суета сосредоточилась в смотровой. Зина оказалась неожиданно в халате, похожем на саван, и начала летать из смотровой в кухню и обратно.
>   **«Пойти, что ль, поесть? Ну их в болото», – решил пес и вдруг получил сюрприз.**
>   – Шарику ничего не давать, – загремела команда из смотровой.
>   .  .  .  .
>
> За розовым стеклом вспыхнул неожиданный и радостный свет, еще больше оттенив черную карточку. Дверь совершенно бесшумно распахнулась, и молодая красивая женщина в белом фартучке и кружевной наколке предстала перед псом и господином. Первого из них обдало божественным теплом, и юбка женщины запахла, как ландыш.
>   **«Вот это да, это я понимаю», – подумал пес.**
>   – Пожалуйте, господин Шарик, – иронически пригласил господин, и Шарик благоговейно пожаловал, вертя хвостом.

Делаем **вывод**: в обязательном порядке при прямой речи в кавычках абзац не нужен (только в диалоге — без кавычек и с начальным тире!), но в принципе, конечно, использоваться может. Все зависит от автора и его ви́дения собственного текста.

[Знаки при прямой речи](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/164-znapr)